# Malware and Virus Scanning Software with a Programmable API for live scanning file bytes

Tags: c++, api, antivirus

We have built an upload filter module with the Native IIS Api in C++.  It's purpose is to prevent blocked file extensions and infected files from being uploaded via IIS websites to the server.

The extension part is done, but now we need to scan byte arrays for malware and viruses, including things like known JPEG data hacks, and null terminating script exploits.

I would like to pass this off to an antivirus program, but would ideally like to do it from RAM without the file ever touching a hard disk with nothing seeing it until the upload filter passes it as ok.

So we are looking for an antivirus program that has some sort of rest based or tcp/ip based API we can call.  Or even C++ headers and lib files we can link in.